# Accessing PHP includes above webroot when running as cron job

Tags: php, apache, cron

I'm trying to use a PHP script with sensitive information so I'm using includes to host the passwords above the webroot.

The script works fine run via the browser, but when I run it as a crob job it generates error messages regarding includes.

The open_basedir setting is: /var/www/vhosts/xxx/:/tmp/ -- wondering if that's relevant here?

Grateful for any suggestions on how to resolve this or workarounds.

```
PHP Warning:  include(../includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/linkedin_status.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  include(../includes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/linkedin_status.php on line 6
PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../includes.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/linkedin_status.php on line 6
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant API_KEY - assumed 'API_KEY' in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/linkedin_status.php on line 88
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant SCOPE - assumed 'SCOPE' in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/linkedin_status.php on line 89
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant REDIRECT_URI - assumed 'REDIRECT_URI' in /var/www/vhosts/xxx.com/httpdocs/linkedin_status.php on line 91
```

Comment: did you try to use absolute path for your `include`? i managed to solve a similar problem this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This always works for me...

```
require_once("/full/path/to/your/file/includes.php");
```

Comment: Thanks -- makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

What you are probably experiencing is that the Cronjob is using a different php.ini, and thus using different settings. To confirm this you can create a php script that writes `phpinfo();` results to a file. In the output you will see which php.ini is being used.

What you can do to fix this is either:

- When executing the cronjob specify which php.ini is to be used.
- Run the cronjob via a wget command that actually executes the script via the webserver, like a browser. Wget is a commannd prompt tool (not PHP!) that calls a url from the internet and writes it to screen or file.